# FROM clause depending on variable value

Tags: sql-server, case

I have two tables with the same column names, and I want to get the data from one or the other depending on one parameter value. What came to mind was something along the lines of

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[traxs_SyncLists_Locations_Search]

    @session_id varchar(30),
    @get_value int,
    @predicate varchar(50),
    @combo varchar(30)

AS

    SELECT
        L.id AS id, 
        L.location AS value
    FROM
        CASE 
            WHEN @combo = 'box' THEN vw_WarehouseLocationBox
            WHEN @combo = 'bay' THEN vw_WarehouseLocationBay
        END L
            LEFT JOIN traxs_temp..__LocationsSyncLists T ON T.session_id = @session_id AND T.id = L.id
    WHERE
        L.whse_no = @get_value AND
        ISNULL(T.archive, 1) = 1 AND
        L.location LIKE @predicate + '%'
```

which was not proper SQL syntax. After some research I wrote

```
SELECT 
    L.id AS id, 
    L.location AS value
FROM
    vw_WarehouseLocationBox L
        LEFT JOIN traxs_temp..__LocationsSyncLists T ON T.session_id = @session_id AND T.id = L.id
WHERE
    @combo = 'box' AND -- TRICK
    L.whse_no = @get_value AND
    ISNULL(T.archive, 1) = 1 AND
    L.location LIKE @predicate + '%'
UNION
SELECT 
    L.id AS id, 
    L.location AS value
FROM
    vw_WarehouseLocationBay L
        LEFT JOIN traxs_temp..__LocationsSyncLists T ON T.session_id = @session_id AND T.id = L.id
WHERE
    @combo = 'bay' AND -- TRICK
    L.whse_no = @get_value AND
    ISNULL(T.archive, 1) = 1 AND
    L.location LIKE @predicate + '%'
```

but I always feel bad about duplicate some code. It is just 2 tables, but what if it is 10 tables later on (could be), should I duplicate this 10 times? Or should I use dynamic SQL, even though I have seen a lot of people advising against it?

Comment: If you have 10 tables with the same type of information you might want to rethink your design strategy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Dynamic SQL, used for the right purposes and written correctly to prevent issues such as SQL Injection attacks. However, I agree that this smells like a poor design.

Comment: Looking at this article it seems that you are right on: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-avoid-conditional-joins-in-t-sql/

Comment: Could you not move the functionality into the business code and have "if type=box then call proc1 else call proc2"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen These tables just have a few columns in common, plus the design is not from me anyway. I just have to cope with what I'm given.

Comment: It is a poor design to have tables that are identical except the name. You should have a single table where you have a column that defines the difference.  Such as `vw_WarehouseLocation` and adda column `Type` that has values `X`=box and `Y`=bay.  You would hen just `select ... from vw_WarehouseLocation WHERE Type=@combo and ...`

Comment: @km This method of table structure works well only when the remaining columns are shared, however if warehouselocationbox had fifteen different columns that didn't apply to warehouselocationbay you end up with lots of nulls and a bad table design.

Comment: @EdwardComeau That's exactly the case.

Comment: @EdwardComeau, in that case create a common table and then FK 1 to 1 speciality tables.  For example: table person (personID, name, age, shoe size, etc),  table fireman (personID, fireStation, truckNumber, etc) table Astronaut (personID, missionCount, rocketnumber, etc)

Comment: @km, yes this would be the preferred method when addressing green field requirements or if the op has control over the table design (however this could be a minor or major redesign effort). It should certainly be listed as a third solution which if you write I will vote up. I think the OP can take away that his problem had three solutions which address a deficiency in the original design and that in all cases using dynamic SQL wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure looks like typeof where WarehouseLocation is the generic type and Box, Bay, etc are extension types.

Your query appears to require only generic information. If you had permissions to do so, I would create a view on top of the prior two view, vw_WarehouseLocation and maintain combination logic here with the union method you have already identified but include an additional field "whse_type" to identify the typeof.

```
create view [vw_WarehouseLocation]
as

select
      [id] as [id]
    , [location] as [location]
    , [whse_no] as [whse_no]
    , 'bay' as [whse_type]
from [vw_WarehouseLocationBay]

union all

select
      [id] as [id]
    , [location] as [location]
    , [whse_no] as [whse_no]
    , 'box' as [whse_type]
from [vw_WarehouseLocationBox]
```

Now you can join this view in not only your current SP but any other object without duplicating the logic here, even if it does seem to be unwieldy and repetitive within the view. This method is more inline with "patching up designs" in a supportable manner.

e.g.,

```
select
      L.id
    , L.location
from vw_WarehouseLocation L
left join traxs_temp..__LocationsSyncLists T
    on T.id = L.id
where L.[whse_type] = @combo
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is the same idea @Dmitry used, but instead of a CTE you're using a "definitive" view, reusable anywhere? +1

Comment: @ArthurRey, exactly that. I was pleased to see his answer with the same concept (I was writing mine at the time).

Answer (score 2):

You could separate mutable and immutable parts. Mutable will contain UNION of basic tables and immutable - other code. Probably it is compromise between duplication and dynamic SQL.

```
WITH L AS (
    SELECT 
        id AS id, 
        location AS value,
        whse_no,
        'box' AS combo
    FROM vw_WarehouseLocationBox
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id, 
        location,
        whse_no,
        'bay'
    FROM vw_WarehouseLocationBay
)
SELECT 
    id,
    value
FROM L
LEFT JOIN traxs_temp..__LocationsSyncLists T ON T.session_id = @session_id AND T.id = L.id
WHERE
    @combo = combo AND
    L.whse_no = @get_value AND
    ISNULL(T.archive, 1) = 1 AND
    L.location LIKE @predicate + '%'
```

Comment: plus one from me, this would be my choice if creating new views wasn't allowed or had some performance advantage (depending on your own mileage). NB, union all could give better performance.

Comment: Thank you @EdwardComeau. I replaced UNION with UNION ALL

Comment: I would have never thought of this kind of design. +1